# syslog-ng control the log from printing multiple time with in given time frame

Tags: syslog-ng

I am new to using syslog-ng, just wondering if syslog-ng provides a way to control the log if the same event is occurred avoid printing the log multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.

For example, the `suppress()` option can be used for such purposes:

https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.26/administration-guide/suppress